# is "each time that" a conjunction that introduces a adverbial clause of time?

Tags: conjunctions

Each time (that) you exercise, you get a little stronger.

This is a sentence from Longman Dictionary. *You exercise* is obviously a finite clause, so I guess each time here is a conjunction. Is this correct?

My second questions is about *that*. In *Each time that you exercise*, what type of clause does that introduce? or why are we using that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Each time (that) you exercise, you get a little stronger.*

"Each time" is a noun phrase headed by the noun "time", with "each" as determiner. "That" is a subordinator introducing a declarative content clause functioning as complement of "time".

The whole noun phrase "each time that you exercise" is a temporal adjunct of frequency.